# Why cannot clang++ deduce the type of a map of lambdas?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, auto

I have the following piece of code:

```
enum RelationalOperator { LT, LTE, EQ, GTE, GT };
std::map<RelationalOperator, bool (*)(const Point&, const Point&)> ops = {
    { GTE, [](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return a >= b; } },
    { LTE, [](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return a <= b; } },
    { EQ, [](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return a == b; } },
    { GT, [](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return a > b; } },
    { LT, [](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return a < b; } },
};
```

This code is inside a template and `Point` is a template parameter.

I tried to replace the type of the variable `ops` with `auto` but Clang++ says:

```
src/utils.hpp:47:10: error: cannot deduce actual type for variable 'ops' with type 'auto' from initializer list
```

Why is that? I thought that the keyword `auto` was for these kinds of situations, where the type is long and fairly obvious.

Comment: It is not *that* obvious that you want a `map` and not a `multimap` or an array of structs.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the actual code causing a problem.

Comment: @BoPersson My bad, I didn't take into account the fact that other objects could have the same initializer list!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, each lambda has its own type, thus given a set of different lambdas, you cannot factor them into a single type without some manual casting (typically embedding them in `std::function<R(Args...)>` objects).

Then, when you write such an initialization:

```
enum RelationalOperator { LT, LTE, EQ, GTE, GT };
std::map<RelationalOperator, bool (*)(const Point&, const Point&)> ops = {
    { GTE, [](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return a >= b; } },
    { LTE, [](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return a <= b; } },
    { EQ, [](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return a == b; } },
    { GT, [](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return a > b; } },
    { LT, [](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return a < b; } },
};
```

What is really happening? It calls the `std::initializer_list` constructor of `std::map<RelationalOperator, bool (*)(const Point&, const Point&)>`. It is also able to deduce that the given braced expression is an initializer list for such a map:

```
std::initializer_list<std::pair<RelationalOperator, bool (*)(Point const&, Point const&)>>
```

Then, an implicit conversion occur for your lambdas.

Now if you write instead:

```
auto ops = {
    { GTE, [](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return a >= b; } },
    { LTE, [](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return a <= b; } },
    { EQ, [](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return a == b; } },
    { GT, [](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return a > b; } },
    { LT, [](const Point& a, const Point& b) { return a < b; } },
};
```

It can't figure out what kind of object is represented by the braced expression (the `T` in the `std::initializer_list<T>`). This is quite explicit in [gcc's error message](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7764f807fc0dcb6c):

```
main.cpp:8:29: error: unable to deduce 'std::initializer_list<auto>' from '{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}'

     auto x = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

                             ^

main.cpp:8:29: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'auto'
```

Answer (score 5):

`auto` doesn't work with initializer lists. The same initializer list could be used to initialize a bunch of other types, for example:

```
std::map<int, bool (*)(const Point&, const Point&)>
std::multimap<RelationalOperator, bool (*)(const Point&, const Point&)>
std::vector<std::pair<int, bool (*)(const Point&, const Point&)>>
```

Answer (score 3):

> I thought that the keyword `auto` was for these kinds of situations, where the type is long and fairly obvious.

The type isn't obvious at all. Each lambda expression produces a unique anonymous closure type, so every element of the initializer list has a different type:

```
auto ops = {
    { GTE, lambda_type_1 },
    { LTE, lambda_type_2 },
    { EQ, lambda_type_3 },
    { GT, lambda_type_4 },
    { LT, lambda_type_5 },
};
```

Each braced initializer has nothing in common. There is nothing obvious about it.

When you initialize the `std::map` there is a constructor taking `std::initializer_list<value_type>` and the compiler can convert each of the initializers to that type. When you replace the map with `auto` there is no clue for the compiler to use to figure out what type you expect it to deduce from a list of unrelated types.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider using STL built-in comparison functors namely `std::equal_to`, `std::less_equal`, `std::greater_equal`, `std::less` and `std::greater` all available in `<functional>` header file.

E.g.:

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>

struct Point {
   bool operator <  (const Point &) const { /* actual implementation */ }
   bool operator <= (const Point &) const { /* actual implementation */ }
   bool operator >  (const Point &) const { /* actual implementation */ }
   bool operator >= (const Point &) const { /* actual implementation */ }
   bool operator == (const Point &) const { /* actual implementation */ }
   /* other stuff */
};

int main() {
   enum RelationalOperator { LT, LTE, EQ, GTE, GT };
    std::map<RelationalOperator, std::function<bool(const Point&, const Point&)>> ops = {
    {GTE, std::greater_equal<Point>()},
    {LTE, std::less_equal<Point>()},
    {EQ, std::equal_to<Point>()},
    {GT, std::greater<Point>()},
    {LT, std::less<Point>()},
   };
}
```